# How can I create lists separated by \n?

Tags: python

I have the following str file (it is a list of items separated into lines):
[lines of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/62lTh.png)

I am trying to separate each line into its own set so it resembles this:
[set of items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9hEnr.png)

I know that I should be using something like .split('\n') and perhaps set() but no matter what combinations I try, I get a list of each individual letter (['c'],['i'],['t'],['r'],['u'],['s']) etc.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you.

Edit: I've added the code below.

The file looks like this:

```
print (groceries_file[0:250] + "...\n... (etc.) ...") # Prints the first 250 characters only

citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups
tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee
whole milk
pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads
other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product
whole milk,butter,yogurt,rice,abrasive clea...
... (etc.) ...
```

The code I have tried is this:

```
groceries = groceries_file.split('/n')
print(groceries)
```

and I get this:

```
['citrus fruit,semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups\ntropical fruit,yogurt,coffee\nwhole milk\npip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads\nother vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product\nwhole milk,butter,yogurt,rice,abrasive cleaner\nrolls/buns\nother vegetables,UHT-milk,rolls/buns,bottled beer,liquor (appetizer)\npot...]
```

Essentially, I'd like to have each line look like: {'citrus fruit', 'semi-finished bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups'} etc.

Comment: Can you post code that you have tried? Images are hard for anyone else to help you by running your code locally

Comment: `/n` is not the same as `\n`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are wrong in someting because use split("\n") is working

```
string="""citrus fruit, semi-finished bread,margarine,ready soups
tropical fruit,yogurt,coffee
whole milk
pip fruit,yogurt,cream cheese ,meat spreads
other vegetables,whole milk,condensed milk,long life bakery product"""
string=string.split('\n')
for item in string:
    print(item.split(","))
```

Comment: I'm not able to edit my post but what I am looking for is this: {'citrus fruit', 'semi-finished bread', 'margarine', 'ready soups'}. Essentially, I am looking to create itemsets for each line. Using just .split creates one long list made up of each line.

Comment: See my edited code

Comment: If you think this answer is useful choose it and accept my answer